# What is office runtime? Where is it useful?

Tags: ms-office, vsto, office-interop, visual-studio-2003

I have a .net solution for converting  word/excel to pdf developed in  MS Visual Studio .Net 2003.I added references i.e., Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel,  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in my project. It is working fine in my local system where MS Office is installed but when I tried to execute in the server where MS Office is not installed, I face some Class ID errors 00024500-0000-0000-c000-000000000046 and 000209FF-0000-0000-c000-000000000046 with respect to Word and excel. So i told my client to install MS Office on server but he wants me to use Office runtime 2010 to convert MS office documents? So what is office runtime actually? Was it helpful in my case? Does MS Office installation is required if I am using VSTO?

I am new here. Kindly help.

Thanks,
Praveen.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Office runtime".

> I added references i.e., Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in my project.

Interop assemblies are used to marshal your calls into unmanaged environment. There is no actual COM servers installed that may handle your calls (i.e. no endpoints).

Anyway, **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

If you deal only with open XML documents you can use the Open XML SDK. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for more information.

But if you need to deal with binary file formats you have to look for third-party components that are designed for the server-side execution.